# Randomly choose two elements from array and swap values in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, swap

I'm writing a program where part of the instructions is to randomly choose two different ord[] elements and then swap their contents. I'm firstly having issues even generating a random element from the array, let alone swapping them (I can't even get it to print the random values). What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry if I'm messing everything up completely. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
#define MMAX 5;
#define ORD_SIZE ( sizeof((ord)) / sizeof((ord[0])) )
int randomOne = 0;
int randomTwo = 0;
int ord[MMAX];

srand(time(NULL));
randomOne = ord[rand() % ORD_SIZE];
randomTwo = ord[rand() % ORD_SIZE];
printf("%d", randomOne);
printf("%d", randomTwo);

int tmp = 0;
tmp = randomOne;
randomOne = randomTwo;
randomTwo = tmp;
printf("%d", ord[randomOne]);
printf("%d", ord[randomTwo]);

return 0;}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm generating these two random elements from this array correctly because my program will not print them

Comment: If you want to swap them, you better to keep their indicies rather than values...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 big problems:

1. You need to generate random indices and swap the elements at those indices, not take 2 random elements of the array:

.

```
randomOne = rand() % ORD_SIZE;
randomTwo = rand() % ORD_SIZE;
printf("%d", ord[randomOne]);
printf("%d", ord[randomTwo]);

int temporary = ord[randomOne];
ord[randomOne] = ord[randomTwo];
ord[randomTwo] = temporary;
```

2. Your array, `ord`, is not initialized.

Also, take a look at http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/. Your "randomness" may be a bit biased towards certain indices.

Comment: Okay I fixed that and it seems to generate two random indices now. So in my original code, is the swapping elements portion correct?

Comment: No, you swapped just the variables. I have added the swap to my answer